# reorder data in database in no particular order

Tags: python, django

I would like to ask. We have an app called Task and the fields in the model are:

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

my concern is, in this task, we would like to allow the user the re-order the task the they have made depending on how they want it to be displayed. I am working on the backend part, I wanted to know how to do it. I came up with one idea but I am not sure how good it is. I added a new field:

```
priority = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

this is the field that will trigger the order in the query "order by". But I do not really know what values I will be putting in there. Should it be something link this

```
id     name     priority
1      task1     1
2      task2     2
3      task3     3
```

for instance, this is the initial data the user input to the database. and  when he wants to change the order like he wants to move task2 to the first place. should the task2 and task1's priority will be modified like:

```
id     name     priority
1      task1     2
2      task2     1
3      task3     3
```

this is the thing I am thinking but I believe there is a better way to do this. Please help me, I know this is kinda vague.

Comment: Although it can be optimised but yes many use this very same approach, It is simple. It just requires more than one write every time you want to re order

Comment: Why `CharField` with length=30? `PositiveSmallIntegerField` is more suitable.